# iPad2 vs iPad3 manually positioned items changing?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad-2, ipad-3

since the iPad 3("The New iPad") has twice the pixels I obliviously have my make any images twice as big. But my question is since it has twice the pixels if I am manually placing an object on screen, with say CGRectMake, will it appear in different places on the iPad2 from the iPad3?
say I'm using the code below to position a button on screen:

```
 CGRectMake(375,500,125,125);
```

since its positioned at 375 pixels on the X coordinate wouldn't it appear in different places on the iPad 2 vs the iPad3 since the iPad3 has twice as many pixels?

I'm sure this is a dumb question that any mildly experienced iOS developer would laugh at but since a simple Google search didn't turn anything up I figured id ask.

Thanks!

-Shredder2794

Answer (score 5):

Though the amount of pixels may differ among devices, Core Graphic's coordinate system does not.  This is because CG expresses itself in points, not pixels.

Comment: Ok thanks, I figured it was something like that but I figured it wa better to ask than to learn the hard way :)